# Divide JSON into equal smaller parts using php

Tags: php, json, split, divide

I have a JSON containing lets say 14 elements.
How can I divide it in smaller JSONs of lets say 2 or 3 elements each.

Comment: Please show us some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not know what your exact json is, but this will serve as an example:

```
<?php

$jsonExample = '["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"]' ;
$arrResult = json_decode($jsonExample,true);
$output = array_chunk($arrResult,3);
var_dump($output);

?>
```

demo:http://codepad.org/aYBg19DB

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using json_decode() and array_chunk().

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php